# Read a list of table names on an Amazon S3 folder under a named folder/directory using boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have a use case where I have to read tables names under a folder on an Amazon S3 given a path.
e.g say a bucket with path `s3://mybucket/aws glue service/raw/source_data/`

in source data there's a folder named Tables that list table names. eg.

Tables:

- users
- customers
- Admin

so basically I want to write a function that returns ["users","customers","Admin"]

Here's what I have so far:

```
def  read_tables(path):
    tables = []
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    bucket = s3.Bucket(path)
    for obj in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='Tables/'):
        tables.append(obj)
    return tables
```

Answer (score 2):

The table name will be at the end of the path of the object key and can be extracted as follows:

```py
def read_tables(s3_uri):
    tables = []
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    remove_scheme = slice(5, len(s3_uri))
    bucketname, key = s3_uri[remove_scheme].split('/', 1) 
    bucket = s3.Bucket(bucketname)
    prefix = f'{key}/Tables/'

    for obj in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=prefix):
        tablename = obj.key.split('/').pop()
        tables.append(tablename)
    return tables
```

Comment: Is path an s3 URI?

Comment: Yes it is @Oluwafemi

Comment: I noticed in the path you shared in the error. You need to extract the bucketname from the S3 URI. `Bucket` instance is constructed with a bucketname

Comment: How do you mean? You pass the  S3 URI to `read_tables`